# Count the number of dinner invitations that are in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `foreach` loop that outputs an array

```
$dinnerDetails = array();
$lastDinnerDate = '';
$newDate = '';
foreach ($invitations as $invitation) {
    $lastDinnerDate = $invitation['dinner_date'];
    if ($invitation['dinner_date'] > $lastDinnerDate) {
        $newDate = 'yes';

    } else {
        $newDate = 'no';
    }

    $dinnerDetails[] = array(
        'request_id' => $invitation['request_id'],
        'dinner_date' => $invitation['dinner_date'],
        'dinner_id' => $invitation['dinner_id'],
        'new_dinner' => $newDate
    );
}
```

Output looks like this

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "48"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "yes"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "51"
    "dinner_id" => "40"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "no"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "50"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "yes"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "52"
    "dinner_id" => "41"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "no"
  ]
]
```

My question is how can i count the number of times the `dinner_id` appeared. I would like to pass that value as part of the array because `$dinnerDetails` is being passed to the view so it will make it easier to display the count. The view already displays the data via `foreach` loop its only the count i need for each `dinner_id`

Comment: this is the same of your array size. so `count(array_column($arr, 'dinner_id'))`

Comment: nope, it can change dynamically, its not fixed

Comment: see updated comment

Comment: what is `$arr` in this case?

Comment: your `$dinnerDetails` array

Comment: Wait, from where your array looks like this?? there are no `dinner_id` in the making of array..

Comment: i am assuming i will be doing this at the end of foreach loop?

Comment: Where are you setting the `dinner_id` ?

Comment: _My question is how can i count the number of times the dinner_id appeared_, From where you want to count??

Comment: `$invitations` is a result of a query from database which already has `dinner_id` in it

Comment: @FrayneKonok i want to count from the start, not sure if i understand your question

Comment: Something isn't matching up, you don't appear to be storing the ID in the new array at all.

Comment: @FrayneKonok sorry, i missed that part out by mistake i have updated the question

Comment: @Epodax sorry, i missed that part out by mistake i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to count the ID's and not the label / name itself, one ever so simple way would be doing it like so, simply place this inside of your `foreach` loop

```
$countDinner[$invitation['dinner_id']] = isset($countDinner[$invitation['dinner_id']]) ? $countDinner[$invitation['dinner_id']] + 1 : 1;
```

One coud also use a if clause instead of a ternary operator if one preffers, don't forget to place a

```
$countDinner = array();
```

Before the `foreach` loop to initialize the array, you should now have a array with the count of each `dinner_id`.

To add it to the existing array simply loop through as following:

```
foreach($dinnerDetails as &$dinnerDetail){
    $dinnerDetail['count'] = $countDinner[$dinnerDetail['dinner_id']];
}
```

and the end result will look like this

```
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "48"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "yes"
    "count" => 2
  ]
```

Comment: Do notice I fixed a missing bracket @Saadia :)

Comment: this does work but can we not make this part of the array that is already being sent to view by adding another key? it will make the life alot easier :)

Comment: @Saadia Try the last line I added.

Comment: still working on it, `$dinnerDetails` gets sent to the view, and inside the view there is a loop that makes use of `$dinnerDetails` to display the data to the user, the way you have done is now added another array `countDinners` which is throwing error

Comment: so I am checking how can i change that a bit

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, your idea worked, i had to change it a small bit i will update your answer by adding the changes required